# How can i program in c++ this board?

Tags: daq-mx

Im trying to make a program in c++ that needs to get data from the board ni pce-6341, but i cant find any library or any information on how to do that.
can somebody tell me where im i supposed to find a library for this, or any other information that can be helpful.

[image: ni pce-6341]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this device and National Instruments products much but a quick search lead me to the [DAQ Getting Started, Read Me First: NI-DAQmx and DAQ Device Installation Guide](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/373235aa.pdf) which mentions C. The more detailed [NI-DAQmx Readme](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/374768ac.html) mentions MFC 9.0 C++ examples in the folder `*...NI-DAQ\Examples\MStudioVC2008` so I assume you will need a full NI install first, then you should search for the examples folder.

Further search gives the [Download NI-DAQmx Shipping Examples](http://www.ni.com/example/53288/en/) page from where drivers can be downloaded and which points to the [NI examples page](http://search.ni.com/nisearch/app/main/p/bot/no/ap/tech/lang/hu/pg/1/sn/catnav:ex/q/daqmx/) where you can search for DAQmx and can download simple examples e.g. [digital port read/write in C](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Read-Write-Digital-Port-DAQmx-ANSI-C/ta-p/3534741?profile.language=en) as well. Also this page states that the examples are installed only when a compatible version of NI-DAQmx is installed, not necessarily with LabView itself.